# unable to load images from storage path on shared hosting in laravel 9 and laravel voyager admin

Tags: laravel

i have a project in laravel 9 with laravel voyager admin panel. my problem is when i am using CLI to launch the app everything is fine but when i upload my website to shared hosting of htdocs (in case of localhost) images from storage folder is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to locate your photo in the public access folder read Voyager documentation and also you need to keep your statice photo in the separate folder